# slicing string in list using list comprehension

Tags: python

I have a list that I want to break into three separate lists created from the first, second, and third positions in the list. It would look something like this:

input:

```
X = ['GCA','GCC','GCT','GCG']
```

output:

```
C1 = ['G', 'G', 'G', 'G']
C2 = ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C']
C3 = ['A', 'C', 'T', 'G']
```

I was thinking about using list comprehension. Doing something like:

```
C1 = [p for p in X if X[0][0]]
```

But I don't know how to slice a string that is inside a list.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `C1, C2, C2 = zip(*X)`

Comment: Why do you want to break up your codons like this anyway? This is clearly DNA

Comment: @Chris_Rands This is an answer, not a comment ...

Comment: Thanks, that helps. @Chris_Rands I am working on a script to give me expanded codons based on amino acid data. I need lists of codons based on position to then compare to a dictionary of expanded codons. Also thanks Zinki, that helps too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Chris_Rands answer using `zip()` is better, but since you also asked about list comprehension:

`C1=[s[0] for s in X]`

works.

`[[s[n] for s in X] for n in range(3))]` would get you all of them as a list.

Output: `[['G', 'G', 'G', 'G'], ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C'], ['A', 'C', 'T', 'G']]`

Answer (score 1):

For your attempt of using comprehension, you just need code like

```
C1 = [p[0] for p in X]
C2 = [p[1] for p in X]
C3 = [p[2] for p in X]
```

or use [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
C1, C2, C3 = zip(*X)
```

Comment: I think you might have got the `zip()` idea from *someone* else, originally you said this wasn't possible ;)